# overlay with `position:fixed` stuck behind <ion-header> on mobile safari `platform=ios`

Tags: ios, css, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to show an overlay with `style={position:fixed,height:100%}` that covers the entire screen. here's a stackblitz that shows it working as intended:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ionic4-test-posfixed

However, when I deploy on `xcode/ios/mobile-safari`, the overlay is stuck behind `<ion-header>`. I can't seem to adjust the CSS `z-index` to make it work.

here's an ionic project with the same components ready to run in `xcode`

https://github.com/mixuala/posfixed.git

```
cd ./posfixed
npm install
ionic serve &
ionic cordova run ios -l
```

Answer (score 0):

It took me awhile to figure it out, but the answer was simple.  `position:fixed` creates a different stacking context. Ultimately, what worked was to add `position:fixed` to all the incorrectly overlayed items at the appropriate time.

```
.show-overlay {
    ion-menu {  
      position:fixed;
    }
    ion-header {
      position:fixed;
    }
    .overlay {
      // now on top of ion-header when platform=ios
      position:fixed;
    }
}
```